# check if variable is null in fish

Tags: shell, fish

I want to check a condition if a variable is null in fish(friendly interactive shell).

```
if test "$argv" = null
    # do something...
else 
    # do something else...
```

Comment: In fish shell, a variable may be "null" in that it expands to an empty string, or it is set to an empty list, or it is not set at all. Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to check if there are arguments on terminal. btw answers worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know "fish" specifically, but I do know the standard "test".

Try:

`test "$argv" = ""`

or

`test "x$argv" = x`

or

`test -z "$argv"`

This assumes you are wanting to test for it being unset or empty.
If you only want one of those two cases, you will need shell specific variable expansion modifiers.

Note that the second sample is often found in code trying for high portability.
It avoids having empty parameters, as they seem to get lost at times.

The third sample is the `test` option to test for an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know fish much either, but like other shells, it also seems to have a distinction between an undefined variable and an empty one.

From the FAQ, it appears that you can [test if a variable is defined](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-check-whether-a-variable-is-defined) with `set -q var`, and use `string length -q` to see if it holds a non-empty string.

For example, to see if the first argument to the script is defined or empty or non-empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
if not set -q argv[1]
    echo 'not defined'
else if not string length -q -- "$argv[1]"
    echo 'defined but empty'
else
    echo 'defined and non-empty'
end
```

If you don't care about the distinction between an undefined and a defined but empty variable, just skip the first test, an undefined value will expand to the empty string when in double-quotes.

Comment: thank you it's helpful. but I already accepted an answer. should I change it and accept your answer? I don't know what to do.